How do I make recurring payments work with commerce and stripe payments
I am stuck with setting up commerce recurring payments. I want to allow subscriptions on my site. So far I have followed the documentation here: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/developer-guide/recurring/getting-started/#setting-up-subscriptions-first-steps
I have set up:

a peyment method (I'd like to add more later)
a billing schedule
created a product variation type (allowed subscriptions)
created a new product

Then, I can add the product to the cart and check out. The initial payment goes through with no problem. I can see it on the stripe test dashboard as well. My issue is when the renewal of the recurring order should happen during cron, a new recurring order is added, but the payment doesn't go through. It is stuck in the state "Needs Payment". Why is that? I dont see anything about this in the documentation. Also "Needs payment" state is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Do I maybe need to enable recurring payments with stripe somehow? (I looked into this but dont see anything about this)(Please see screenshot below)
Im seeking help at this point. I apprechiate any comment and help. Thank you!


This question is similar to: How to set up a recurring payment. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Recurring payments are complex to set up and there is no "just install this and you're done" solution for Drupal Commerce.  Stripe subscriptions made in the Stripe interface are different from Commerce subscriptions; you have to choose one or the other.  As for why the payment isn't being updated, you need to turn on logging in Commerce and you might also need to log the response you are getting from Stripe, if any.  Stripe also has a webhook endpoint you can call to check subscription status.

Thank you, Patrick for your answer. I think it's better if I implement stripe myself as I don't need most of the functionality, the module provides and it seems this is just too much of a hustle for some reason. Hopefully in the future there will be a straightforward step-by-step guide to do this. Thank you again. Have a nice day.
